# Asseration failed error while searching for Active Sound

Tags: c++, audio, unreal-engine4

I want to get `PlaybackTime` from `FActiveSound` class. However i always get this error:

```
 Assertion failed: IsInAudioThread()
```

when i call this:

```
FActiveSound* ActiveSound = AudioDevice->FindActiveSound(AudioComponent->GetAudioComponentID());
```

My question is why is that? It may be nooby question but I cannot make it work on myself.

EDIT:1
What I'm doing atm is this:
`Binding delegate : AudioComponent->OnAudioPlaybackPercent.AddDynamic(this, &UAudioController::GimmePlaybackPosition);`

then there is my function which looks like this:

`void UAudioController::GimmePlaybackPosition(const USoundWave* SoundWave, float PlaybackPercent)
{
    FAudioDevice* AudioDevice = GEngine->GetAudioDevice();
    if (AudioDevice)
    {
        FActiveSound* ActiveSound;
    }
    //GEngine->AddOnScreenDebugMessage(-1, 15.0f, FColor::Red, TEXT("Delegate fire"));
}`
And now I'm wondering, how can I get there my AudioComponent, to get PlaybackTime ;/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to run the code that accesses `AudioDevice` in the audio thread via `FAudioThread::RunCommandOnAudioThread`.

Here is a snippet used in `AudioComponent.cpp`:

```
if (FAudioDevice* AudioDevice = GetAudioDevice())
{
    const uint64 MyAudioComponentID = AudioComponentID;
    FAudioThread::RunCommandOnAudioThread([AudioDevice, MyAudioComponentID, InName, InFloat]()
    {
        FActiveSound* ActiveSound = AudioDevice->FindActiveSound(MyAudioComponentID);
        if (ActiveSound)
        {
            ActiveSound->SetFloatParameter(InName, InFloat);
        }
    }, GET_STATID(STAT_AudioSetFloatParameter));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I'm a bit lost becouse of documentation is so bad. I've started to look into engine code, which hopefully will be more beneficial for me :D That code tho helped me  a ton, so thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The error usually means that you tried to access `AudioDevice` from a wrong thread. Perhaps, you should post your code to get better answers.

Comment: Edited my question with my code. Still have no clue how can I pass my Audio Component inside or get it from there